# asp.net application with windows authentication and custom membership provider advice

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-authentication, membership-provider

I’ve been asked to upgrade a few applications and I’m planning on merging all of them into one asp.net application. I’m fine with this decision and have spoken with fellow workers and they also think it’s the best option to go with.

The application will be accessed from a small group of users which belong to a larger domain. I’m currently planning on using Windows authentication and only allow this small set of users to access the asp.net application.  Also there must be some role management, so that only certain users can view certain functionality.

I really don’t want to have many different windows groups; so I want to avoid having to assign different windows groups to different folders and control permissions in the web.config.

What I’d like to do is: 
-   Assign one windows group to the small group of users who will access the page.
-   Create a custom membership provider and control the user who accesses the application. Depending on the user I will then assign his current set of roles.
-   Add an application setting to the web.config, with the name of the current administrator, so if he logs in, he will be assigned all roles, and will be able to create and assign roles to other users.

I’d appreciate some advice if this would be the correct way to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx).

I like to use this.  You can create a global security group (one for each 'role').  The account management namespace will allow you to fetch the UserPrincipal from AD with their logon name from the http context.  Then you can check them for memebership in the security groups you created using the .IsMemberOf Method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I’ve had a quick look at the namespace you advised and it seems like ,a part from other things, allows you to create AD groups from code and assign them to users. I’m planning in only assigning a unique windows group to the users which will have permission to access the site.

Comment: This is not a web application?